# StaticImage in a layer. Is the change of source synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: image, asynchronous, openlayers

I'm developing a an application which displays images ( png ) in a layer of an OpenLayer's map. So far so good, it works like a charm. Nonetheless it may happen
that the requested image has to be created on the fly by the server and then a delay of few or more seconds can be observed before the image appears on the client's side. To make the user understand that displaying the image takes some time I use an animation that appears when the request is sent to the server and should disappear when the image is served and displayed (see code below). What I observe though is that the animation never appears exactly as is the service of the image was processed in an asynchronous way. I really would like to know if my interpretation is correct and in such a case which can of event I should trap and only then make the animation disappear.

```js
document.getElementById('loading').style.display='block';
_im_layer_1 = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://'+server+':'+port+'/png/?path="'+_path+'"&si='+_sliceIndex,
        projection: _projection_1,
        imageExtent: _extent
      })
    });

    console.log("adding the image layer");
    _map_1.addLayer(_im_layer_1);

document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was expecting to listen to the source with

```
imageStaticSource.on('change', evt => {
  console.log('no event, contrary to what I would expect');
});
```

but it fails contrary to what I expected from the API docs.

So, looking at the code, I've seen there is an `imageLoadFunction` option for the `ol.source.ImageStatic` constructor. When not set, this function fallback to a default one. I've created a new one, derived from the default and made some changes to demonstrate how you can get the start of the loading event and then the end of it.

You will find [a demo derived from the official sample](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/47d905ddd664024dab1eb0f194348cd0) that should illustrate the process. Try it on you side as the demo does not wait some seconds to return the image, contrary to your use case.

```
var imageLoadFunction = function(image, src) {
  // Where you start showing the loader using a variable
  console.time('loader');
  image.getImage().addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Where you should mention to stop the loader
    console.timeEnd('loader');
  });
  image.getImage().src = src;
};

 var imageStaticSource = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  attributions: '© <a href="http://xkcd.com/license.html">xkcd</a>',
  url: 'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/online_communities.png',
  projection: projection,
  imageLoadFunction: imageLoadFunction,
  imageExtent: extent
});
```